# PL/pgSQL: structure of query does not match function result type

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table

```
create table abac_object (
    inbound abac_attribute,
    outbound abac_attribute,
    created_at timestamptz not null default now(),

    primary key (inbound, outbound)
);
```

`abac_attribute` is my custom type that is defined like

```
create type abac_attribute as (
    value text,
    key text,
    namespace_id uuid
);
```

I try to create a number of functions that work over the table

```
create function abac_object_list_1(_attr abac_attribute)
returns setof abac_object as $$
    select *
    from abac_object
    where outbound = _attr
$$ language sql stable;

create function abac_object_list_2(_attr1 abac_attribute, _attr2 abac_attribute)
returns setof abac_object as $$
    select t1.*
    from abac_object as t1
    inner join abac_object as t2 on t1.inbound = t2.inbound
    where
        t1.outbound = _attr1
        and t2.outbound = _attr2
$$ language sql stable;

create function abac_object_list_3(_attr1 abac_attribute, _attr2 abac_attribute, _attr3 abac_attribute)
returns setof abac_object as $$
    select t1.*
    from abac_object as t1
    inner join abac_object as t2 on t1.inbound = t2.inbound
    inner join abac_object as t3 on t1.inbound = t3.inbound
    where
        t1.outbound = _attr1
        and t2.outbound = _attr2
        and t3.outbound = _attr3
$$ language sql stable;

create function abac_object_list(_attrs abac_attribute[], _offset integer, _limit integer)
returns setof abac_attribute as $$
begin
    case array_length(_attrs, 1)
        when 1 then return query
            select t.inbound
            from abac_object_list_1(_attrs[1]) as t
            order by t.created_at
            offset _offset
            limit _limit;
        when 2 then return query
            select t.inbound
            from abac_object_list_2(_attrs[1], _attrs[2]) as t
            order by t.created_at
            offset _offset
            limit _limit;
        when 3 then return query
            select t.inbound
            from abac_object_list_3(_attrs[1], _attrs[2], _attrs[3]) as t
            order by t.created_at
            offset _offset
            limit _limit;
        else raise exception 'bad argument' using detail = 'array length should be less or equal to 3';
    end case;
end
$$ language plpgsql stable;
```

`abac_object_list_1` works fine

```
select *
from abac_object_list_1(('apple', 'type', '00000000-0000-1000-a000-000000000010') ::abac_attribute);
```

However with `abac_object_list` I get the following error

```
select *
from abac_object_list(array [('apple', 'type', '00000000-0000-1000-a000-000000000010')] :: abac_attribute[], 0, 100);
```

> [42804] ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type Detail: Returned type abac_attribute does not match expected type text in column 1. Where: PL/pgSQL function abac_object_list(abac_attribute[],integer,integer) line 4 at RETURN QUERY

I can't understand where `text` type comes from.

These functions worked before but then I added `created_at` column to be able to add explicit `ORDER BY` clause. And now I can't rewrite functions correctly.

Also maybe there is a better (or more idiomatic) way to define these function.

Could you please help me to figure it out?
Thank you.

P. S.

Well, it seems to work if I write

```
return query select (t.inbound).*
```

But I am not sure if it is a right approach.
Also I wonder what is better to use `return table` or `return setof`.